# Extracting a UV layout

Tags: texturing

I have a 3D truck model already textured and properly imported into Blender. This is a game model and I need to "re-paint" with design from other transport companies. The problem is that I don't have a UV layout (skin template) to serve as a guide for future paintings.

**Is there a way to "extract" an UV Layout to .JPG or .PNG to serve as guide for .DDS texture editing?**

Please note that I don't want to remap the model. I still want to use the actual UV Mapping and just need to edit the actual textures.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Yes**.

In *Image editor > Header > UVs*, select *Export UV layout*:

[image]

This will take you to the file manager and allow you to set the export options:

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to switch the Image Editor to "View" mode, else the UV menu isn't accessible ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Faewn.png)).

Comment: Also, you must select all of the models edges before attempting to export or you will not get the outline as part of the exported image file.