# How can I create an image of my UV unwrap

Tags: texturing

I've created a model, and I'm preparing to texture it. I've marked all the seams, unwrapped it and moved it around to my desires. I am ready to create an image for my model. Usually, I would see people creating the texture, then align the UV unwrap to the image (of the texture). In my case, I only have the unwrap. I do *not* have an image file (a texture). I am looking to create an image file of my UV unwrap which I can use to place a texture on. Maybe have the islands in white, and the rest in black? I am not sure how to approach such an idea. How can I create an image of my UV unwrap; an image that separates the islands in a different color in a way where I can texture it? Thanks.

Comment: You can use the 'Export UV Layout' option. It will export your UV islands to the .png file e.g. Then you can overlay the texture on it in gimp or a photoshop. See how to do it here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16384/extracting-a-uv-layout

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16384/extracting-a-uv-layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the bottom of the "UV Image Editor" window, open the "UVs" menu and click "Export UV Layout."[image]

You will then get a "Save as" menu where you can specify where to save a PNG file. You can also change it to a different resolution or image type with the options in the lower left.[image]

The default exported PNG image will have a grey outline of the UV map filled in with transparent white. The rest of the image is also transparent so you can put it over top another image in a photo editor like GIMP and still see the image underneath.
Good luck.