# How can I use Photoshop to edit the textures of my model?

Tags: texturing, export, texture-painting

I have a 3d model in Blender and I was wondering if I could open it in Adobe Photoshop to texture it.

I can't use photoshops 3D features because my computer is to slow.

Is there any way to open my 3d model in Photoshop to texture it?

Answer (score 3):

You can sort of "open" 3d model in Photoshop ([example](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/essential-3d-concepts-tools-photoshop.html)), but it's not something as flexible as editing it with 3d package (and that won't provide you with most features like what is expected when importing 3d models) . What Blender provides you with is to edit the *texture* of the model with any image editing program. There are 2 possible ways:

- [editing image used as texture directly in image editing software](https://www.blender.org/manual/ru/sculpt_paint/painting/texture_paint/introduction.html#using-an-external-image-editor). Note that you might want to [export UV layout](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16384/extracting-a-uv-layout) in order to be able to see what faces you're painting on;
- export current position of the mesh in the viewport to the image editing program, paint on the mesh like it was visible when captured in 3-rd party program and then apply those changes back to the image texture in Blender. This feature is called *Quick Edit* (image painting program [should be set up in the User Preferences](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/preferences/file.html#file-paths)):

  [image]

Comment: You can open 3d models in Photoshop..Check this https://youtu.be/Li5s0WMVbtE

Comment: @MrCSS That's kind of feature with unclear goal and sense, but yes, it's present, fixed. In this case your question is off-topic here.