# Unwrapping from Textured Model

Tags: uv, unity

I have a rectangular cube. I have unwrapped each face separately, then used an image in the UV editor, grabbed and moved the UV face around, scaled as I like, and then I moved on to the next face. I did this for all faces. In my 3D View window, using Texture as my Viewpoint Shading, it looks great. Now, I want to generate a UV map from the completed model, for use in Unity. For use in Blender, I would not need a UV Map, but for exporting the model and exporting the UV map for other software, like Unity, to read, it is necessary. How can I make a UV map from my completed, textured model? I scaled the image, the image tiled itself onto the face to fill the face. Any suggestions? I think there is a way to do this.[image]

Comment: UV maps aren't exported separately, they are an integral part of mesh data and exported with by default. If you want to export the **UV Layout** for reference purposes to paint over it in, say, GIMP or Photoshop then you[• can do so from the *UV Image Editor*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16384/extracting-a-uv-layout)

Comment: I can't seem to do it, and I'm not sure that method will work. Since I scaled the images by face on the texture image. As I scaled the image, the image tiled itself onto the face to fill the face. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you did or what your intentions are. Could you add some images to your question by pressing the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/82285/edit) and clarifying what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Having previously worked mostly in AutoDesk software to do UVs, I missed a couple steps that I did not have to do in software like Maya.
Solution:
1) Selected edges
2) Marked seams
3) Applied Scale and Rotation using Control-A
4) Unwrapped using basic UV Unwrap

Blender adds things like Smart Unwrap, which some might find useful, I find it just gets in the way. AutoDesk also allows you to skip steps like marking seams and has a smarter UV Window Editor. Blender is free, and now that I have the hang of this, I'm sticking with free Blender at the cost of just two fairly easy steps. Room for improvement, if you see this, Blender devs, but works great!

Comment: Check out [10 Essential UV Tips and Tricks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brnaAL-QwhU)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new UV map in the Properties window, and then you can set it as active and unwrap to a new blank image with no overlapping faces. You can then bake from one uv map to the other so that you end up with an image that maps with no repeated faces - if that is what you have in mind.Here in this image you can see the UV map named Bake and how it is set to view, and the bake settings to just 'texture'. The bake has left the single image now in 6 places matched to each face in the new image, compared to the original one image with multiple overlapped faces.[image: baked from one uv to another image and uv map]

edit:
1. Object must already have UV unwrap with an UV mapping in the Properties panel and main image texture(s) in the material texture slot(s)
2. Load a new image in the UV image editor while in edit mode, NOT added to the material
3. Add a new UV layer and click the camera icon next to it
4. Unwrap the mesh again, in this instance I used Smart UV Unwrap
5. In the Render tab under Bake, choose 'Textures' and press Bake
6. Result should fill the new image with details from the other texture(s)
7. Save result image to disk

Once you are there, you may save a copy of your file and then delete the unused UV layer.

Comment: I'm trying to follow along. I created a new UV Map under Data from the Properties window. To set it as active, do I click the camera to the right? Then, how do I bake from one UV to another? I tried going to Render and then bake, but that did not help, it just turned my model all white. I did all the editing by scaling and moving my image in editor, and if you look at my model, it's perfect, like I want it. I'm just trying to get the UVs from the model. Maybe I'm just not understanding your method.

Comment: I've redone a UV Map, but whenever I click "Bake", it ignores my texture or UV Map, and just changes it to the default RGBA color. Why is this happening?

Comment: Let me add the specific steps in the answer above