# Brickifying a structure

Tags: texture-painting

I  am working on a Bridge, and I have already made the model. I would like to know if there is a fast way to paint a bumpmap that makes it look like it's made out of bricks.

And if there is no way to do it and I just wasted a lot of my life, how should I do structures like this in the future?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? You don't know how to paint a nump map, or you don't know if painting a bumpmap is the right approach? In the last case I would suggest to better explain what you have done so far.

Comment: You want them to be clean or old and dirty? There is procedural Texture "Bricks" but it need a bit of love to look slightly realistic.

Comment: Well, I don't really want it to be super realistic, and my problem is with painting an exact pattern. I know that a bump or a normal map is the right approach, and I know how to paint them. But the Brick texture isn't really good for this, as I would like to make something that really fits the mesh

Comment: Maybe look at the way the uvs are scaled up and down on this model as a hint to how to do it - use a single brick pattern image and convert to normal/bump map in photo editor https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82285/unwrapping-from-textured-model/82288?noredirect=1#comment145232_82288

Comment: The problem is that the structure is very complicated, so I can't easily apply a brick texture onto it. I thought that the easiest method would be to draw a grid, but I don't know if there are any ways to draw lines that are exactly the same distance from each other.